# Meteor Collection.find() everything except a value

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I want meteor to return all Items that have not been marked as inactive. The inactive flag is just set if the item is marked inactive.

Marking an Item as inactive:

```
Template.displayedItems.events({
    'change [type=checkbox]': function(event) {
    var checked = $(event.target).is(':checked');
    Items.update(this._id, {$set: {inactive: checked}});
}
```

How do I have to query to get all items that are not inactive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the documents for which the value of the `inactive` field is not set, you can probably use [$exists](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/#op._S_exists)

```
Items.find({inactive : { $exists: false }})
```

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
Items.find({inactive : false})
```

Should do the trick. Check [the doc](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/selectors) for more!